# How can I unlock more new cards?

Tags: xbox-360, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

I am playing Magic 2013 on Xbox, and was pleased to discover that the number of available cards per deck was increased from 30 to 40. However, when I won a game with a deck that I had at 30/40 cards unlocked, I did not gain a new card.

I have not unlocked any decks beyond what the game comes with.

Will I eventually gain access to these extra cards?

Comment: I think the cards may be locked to an expansion pack.

Comment: @manontheside they have released other expansion packs without listing them in the deck manager screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10 additional cards can only be unlocked via a promo code. Fortunately, they're only [a Google search away](https://www.google.com/search?q=duels+2013+promo+codes+expansion). To unlock, go to the Player Status screen and enter the codes.

Comment: How do I enter these codes on Xbox?

Comment: @ChargingPun: Go to the `Player Status` screen, select `MtG Promo Unlocks` and enter away.